# When a dielectric is polarized due to an electric field does it get deformed?

Tags: electrostatics, dielectric

I think the answer is yes. There is an equivalent bound surface and volume charge in the dielectric, therefore some forces exist locally. So this should also be the reason why some dielectrics will stick to your hair after rubbing?

Answer (score 0):

Piezoelectric materials do get deformed in electric fields.